# Image height is not getting fitted to its parent widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Image is not fitted to the card widget even after placing inside `FittedBox()`, also tried with `BoxFit`

```
 child: Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: Card(
                  
                    
                      child:Column(children: [
                         if(key.urlToImage!=null)
                          
                           FittedBox(
                             fit:BoxFit.cover,
                             child: Image(

                               image:NetworkImage(key.urlToImage)))else CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

**Error:**

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 320
> pos 12:  'width > 0.0': is not true.
>
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
> shouldprovide substantially more information in this error message to
> help you determine and fix the      underlying cause. In either case,
> please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:   FittedBox
> file:///C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/newsApp/newsapp/lib/screens/feedScreen.dart:69
> :32

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `FittedBox` and use the `Image`'s `fit` parameter (I also removed the `Column`).

```
Container(
  height: 200.0,
  child: Card(
    child: if(key.urlToImage!=null) Image(
      image: NetworkImage(key.urlToImage),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ) else CircularProgressIndicator()
  ),
),
```

Comment: But i need the column widget for placing other widgets that comes after the image.
If i remove the column widget how will i place them?

Comment: Since you were using the image as a cover, I thought you won't put other widgets inside the `Column` (they'll be covered by the image). Anyways, you can put the `Column` back into place, but wrap it into a `SingleChildScrollView` to avoid overflow. @SamuelT